# Get records where values came from another table field SQL query

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables `notes & folders`.

`notes`

```
id | title    | folder_id
1   sample1      1
2    test        2
3    parent      0
```

`folders`

```
id  |   name   | is_locked
1     another      1
2      test        0
3      test2       null
```

Now, I want to retrieve the notes where folders.is_locked is not equal to 1 ( 1 means locked folders) or folder_id = 0.

My current table records is 5 where 1 record belongs to a locked folder while the remaining 4 records belongs to unlocked folders. But my sql query below returns empty records:

```
 SELECT * FROM notes AS note
 INNER JOIN folders AS folder
   ON folder.id=note.folder_id
 WHERE folder.is_locked != 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add sample data for both tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check. I just added data

Comment: What's your expected results from those sample tables?

Comment: `I want to retrieve the notes where folders.is_locked is not equal to 1 ( 1 means locked folders).` Here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT` join and return the unmatched rows:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM notes AS n LEFT JOIN folders AS f
ON f.id = n.folder_id AND f.is_locked = 1
WHERE f.id IS NULL;
```

or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM notes AS n
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM folders f
  WHERE f.id = n.folder_id AND f.is_locked = 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dee619621ae13eaadcd08de8dc66bd60).